# Replacing BB Code table tag using preg_replace

Tags: php, bbcode

i have the below string.

```php
$string="My Table
[table][tr][th]No.[/th][th]Content[/th][/tr][tr][td]1[/td][td]First[/td][/tr][tr][td]2[/td][td]Second[/td][/tr][tr][td]3[/td][td]Third[/td][/tr][/table]";
```

i want to replace this in to the following format.

```php
$string="My Table<br><table><tr><th>No.</th><th>Content</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>First</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Second</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Third</td></tr></table>
```

I am trying to create a BBcode with preg_match. Please help.

I tried the following but it do not make the table tag mandatory. If some one do not close the table tag it makes issue to the whole page css.

```php
    $string = preg_replace("#\[table\](.*?)\[\/table]#",'<table style=\'border:1px solid;\'>$1</table>',$Text);
    $Text = preg_replace("#\[tr\](.*?)\[\/tr]#is",'<tr style=\'border:1px solid;\'>$1</tr>',$Text);
    $Text = preg_replace("#\[td\](.*?)\[\/td]#is",'<td style=\'border:1px solid;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;\'>$1</td>',$Text);
    $Text = preg_replace("#\[th\](.*?)\[\/th]#is",'<th style=\'border:1px solid;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;\'>$1</th>',$Text);
```

Comment: If you're going to support BBCode (or any known format like that), wouldn't it be easier to use [some already existing, and well tested, library](https://packagist.org/?query=bbcode)? Things like _"If some one do not close the table tag it makes issue to the whole page css"_, and if things can be written in different ways, can usually not be fixed by regular expressions alone (since it then would be more irregular than regular).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just made a mistake, you need to use the same result in your next preg_replace.

Your variable **$string** is not reused after ...

Simply rename it to **$Text**